# What is a Fascia Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Fascia Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| FASCIA Words™ | Not FASCIA Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| HOMBERG | EXTATIC |
| WOOZILY | DURABLE |
| SKIRTED | NARCISM |
| BOARISH | TABLEAU |
| FACTUAL | EASIEST |
| ARCTOID | HUSKILY |
| DECODED | KINETIC |
| ROOTERS | FACTURE |
| TRIGRAM | MOULTER |
| SIDLING | EASELED |
| ROOIBOS | MIXTURE |

The CSV version:

```
FASCIA Words™,Not FASCIA Words™
HOMBERG,EXTATIC
WOOZILY,DURABLE
SKIRTED,NARCISM
BOARISH,TABLEAU
FACTUAL,EASIEST
ARCTOID,HUSKILY
DECODED,KINETIC
ROOTERS,FACTURE
TRIGRAM,MOULTER
SIDLING,EASELED
ROOIBOS,MIXTURE
```

These are not the only examples of Fascia Words™, many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

**HINT 1:**

> A hint exists among the parallel structure. The words exist within the given words. Astounded, the worker saw this but the answer flew in his face. It was right there on his fascia.

**HINT 2:**

> What is a fascia? A fascia is something that is generally the covering or front of an object or thing. It is a term used across multiple industries, especially construction and biological.

**HINT 3:**

> If you look at the face,
> thrice you will trace;
> if you see the inverse,
> you'll be sure to infer

**HINT 4:**

> Jump thrice, jump once, jump no more
> on the face it's not a bore
> bounce right back and go again
> you'll find the clue in view within

Comment: extatic ... isn't a word? or is obsolete and/or common misspelling of ecstatic, surely.

Comment: extatic is an obsolete spelling of ecstatic. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extatic "1749, [John Cleland], in Memoirs of a Woman of Pleasure [Fanny Hill], London: Printed [by Thomas Parker] for G. Fenton [i.e., Fenton and Ralph Griffiths] […], OCLC 731622352:
for, whilst he hesitated there, the crisis of pleasure overtook him, and the close compressure of the warm surrounding fold drew from him the extatic gush"

Comment: ... as my comment said, "**obsolete** and/or common misspelling"

Comment: as I said, I was confirming which of the two. You said two different things. I told which one it was. It also is a common misspelling but for the purposes of this post, it is simply an obsolete spelling and should be treated as a regular word and nothing less.

Comment: Is the capitalization important?

Comment: @Benja The capitilization is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Found a hint, but can't get the rest.

> HOME
> WOOD
> SKIN
> BOAT
> FACE
> ARCH
> DECK
> ROOF
> TRIM
> SIDE
> ROOM

Comment: This is all I've ever found in this puzzle too (first 3 of left, first of right, for those who are wondering how to derive this - it's what all the 'jumps' and 'traces' in the hints are about). However, since the answer to this type of puzzle can usually be found without any interrelation between the two sets of words I still have no idea how to translate this into the intended answer...

Comment: Most of these words seem to relate to architecture, but I'm not sure what to make of that, let alone the outliers...

Comment: You've solved the puzzle, but what's the rule? By the way, the part about the second column is part of the hint, not the rule.

Comment: If someone doesn't find the rule I might forget the rule lol. I still remember it